# Irreducibility of superelliptic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero, let $a,d$ be integers, and let $f\in k[x]$ be a separable polynomial of degree $d$.

Question: a) Is the affine plane curve $y^a=f(x)$ irreducible for all $a\geq 2$ and $d\geq 3$?

b) Same question as in a) but with $k$ of positive characteristic.

Comment: This is not suitable for MO. Not voting to close yet, as I don't know your background. In case you really need the answers, yes for (a) and for (b) if and only if the characteristic does not divide $a$.

Comment: Dear Felipe Voloch, thanks a lot for answering my questions. I am new on MO and I am sorry that the questions are not suitable for MO.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing. I am wrong on (b). It's always irreducible too.

Comment: Dear Felipe, I was about to ask you about (b). If I am not mistaken, 
a) and b) have positive answers even only for $d>0$ (one can apply 
Eisenstein's criterion in $(k[x])[Y]$). 